# Python GDAL: How to create virtual raster and cut out the polygon?

Tags: python, gdal

I would like to create virtual mosaic by gdal and then cut out the polygon and save it. The problem is I can't create virtual mosaic. How to solve that?

Error:

```
TypeError: invalid path or file: <osgeo.gdal.Dataset; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *' at 0x0000022773083B40> >
```

The code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
import rasterio
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/warstwa_testowa.xlsx')

a = 'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/73776_931613_M-34-46-C-d-3-3.tif'
b = 'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/73776_933044_M-34-58-A-b-1-1.tif'
lista_tiff = [a, b]
             
completed_tif = gdal.BuildVRT('Vector_district.vrt', lista_tiff)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    coo = shapely.wkt.loads(row['geometry'])
    multiplier = int(row['liczba_kon'])
    coo_buffer = coo.buffer(2 * multiplier)
    lokalnyid = row['lokalnyid']
    with rasterio.open(completed_tif) as src:
        out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, [coo_buffer], crop=True)
        out_meta = src.meta
        out_meta.update(
            {
                "driver": "GTiff",
                "height": out_image.shape[1],
                "width": out_image.shape[2],
                "transform": out_transform,
            }
        )
        with rasterio.open(f'C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/{lokalnyid}.tif', "w", **out_meta) as dest:
            dest.write(out_image)
```

Comment: you use a full path for everything except the vrt so you probably don't have write permissions for the directory you are running in (and with windows that is always a guess) so use a full path for it

Comment: Thanks, but the code is is correct?

Comment: Who knows? the error says you are using an invalid path, so fix that first and see what happens

Comment: `gdal.BuildVRT('Vector_district.vrt', lista_tiff)` (no `completed_tif = `) then pass the vrt filename or path instead of a `gdal.Dataset`, i.e `with rasterio.open('Vector_district.vrt')`